# RKHS of functions vanishing at single point

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, reproducing-kernel-hilbert-spaces

> **[Exercise 5.3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EI2WT.png).** Let $\mathcal H$ be an RKHS on $X$ with reproducing kernel $K$, fix $x_0\in X$ and let $\mathcal H_0=\{f\in\mathcal H: f(x_0)=0\}$. Compute the kernel function for $\mathcal H_0$.

It is easy to show that $H_{0}$ is RKHS and I am aware of the fact that if $P:H\rightarrow H_{0}$ is the orthogonal projection then the kernel of $H_{0}$ is $K_{0}(x,y)=\langle Pk_{y},k_{x}\rangle$. My question is how to calculate the kernel explicitly?

I tried to find a function $\phi:X\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ such that $\phi(x_{0})=0$ and for every function $f\in H_{0}$ there exist a function $g\in H_{0}$ such that $f(x)=\phi(x)g(x)$. Also if the multiplication operator $M_{\phi}$ on $H$ is isometry, then $f(x)=\phi(x)g(x)=\phi(x)\langle g,k_{x}\rangle=\phi(x)\langle \phi g,\phi k_{x}\rangle= \langle \phi g,\phi k_{x}\overline{\phi(x)}\rangle=\langle f,\phi k_{x}\overline{\phi(x)}\rangle$.

Then the kernel of $H_{0}$ is $K_{0}(y,x)=\phi(y) k(y,x)\overline{\phi(x)}$. But I am not able to find such $\phi$.

Please help me regarding this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It might be good idea to include the source of the problem. A Google search suggests that it might be the book [An Introduction to the Theory of Reproducing Kernel Hilbert Spaces](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22An+Introduction+to+the+Theory+of+Reproducing+Kernel+Hilbert+Spaces%22) by Vern I. Paulsen, Mrinal Raghupathi. An exercise with this text is shown [on page 80](https://books.google.com/books?id=rEfGCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA80).

Answer (score 4):

I have to admit that I cannot really follow what you are trying to do. How do you justify the existence of $g$?

Here is a way to find $K_0$. The subspace $H_0$ consists of those $f$ such that
$$
0=f(x_0)=\langle f,k_{x_0}\rangle. 
$$
Thus $H_0=\{k_{x_0}\}^\perp$. So $P=I-Q$, where $Q$ is the orthogonal projection onto $\mathbb C\,k_{x_0}$. That is,
$$
Qg=\frac{\langle g,k_{x_0}\rangle}{\|k_{x_0}\|^2}\,k_{x_0}.
$$
Then
$$
Pk_y=k_y-=\frac{\langle k_y,k_{x_0}\rangle}{\|k_{x_0}\|^2}\,k_{x_0},
$$
and
$$
K_0(x,y)=\langle Pk_y,k_x\rangle=\langle k_y,k_x\rangle-\frac{\langle k_y,k_{x_0}\rangle}{\|k_{x_0}\|^2}\,\langle k_{x_0},k_x\rangle
=K(x,y)-\frac{K(x_0,y)K(x,x_0)}{K(x_0,x_0)}.
$$